# Livedata not triggering in fragment after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

After configuration change, the observer is not triggered anymore in my fragment. I really can't understand what I'm missing in the code (it is using latest androidx support libraries).

**Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    itemListFragment = (ItemListFragment) fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.container_fragment_items);

    if (itemListFragment == null) {
    itemListFragment = ItemListFragment.newInstance();
    fragMgr.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_fragment_items, itemListFragment)
            .commit();
    }
...
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mainViewModel.getAllItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), items -> adapter.setItems(items));
...
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MainRepository mMainRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Item>> mAllItems;

    public MainViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mMainRepository = new MainRepository(application);
        mAllItems = mMainRepository.getAll();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getAllItems() {
        return mAllItems;
    }
...
```

Comment: That `if` check will only work if this Axctivity only shows that 1 Fragment, which typically is not the case. Otherwise I do not see anything technically wrong... unless the error is in `MainRepository`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks it was because of that `if`, but Why? Do I need that if at all? Could you please help me.

Comment: Without that `if`, maybe I should `replace` the fragment instead of `add`ing?

Comment: actually, that if should be `if(savedInstanceState == null) {`. I'm surprised I didn't mention that. I personally just generally don't trust `findFragmentById` and always find them by tag